# Javascript variable scope issue between functions

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var currentTemp = 0;
  $.simpleWeather({
    location: 'New York, New York',
    woeid: '',
    unit: 'f',
    success: function(weather) {
      currentTemp = weather.temp;
    },
    error: function(error) {
      currentTemp = 150;
    }
  });
  $('#degrees').text(currentTemp);
```

For some reason, the variable *currentTemp*'s value, when set inside the *simpleWeather* function, doesn't carry outside of this function. What can I do?

Comment: put `$('#degrees').text(currentTemp);` inside success function

Comment: `simpleWeather` is async ... your call ` $('#degrees').text(currentTemp);` runs *before* the `success` method runs.

Comment: It's a timing issue, not a scope issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#degrees').text(currentTemp)` doesn't wait for $.simplerWeather to fire up `success` handler. You should move whatever code you need to execute *after* the `$.simplerWeather` to the `success` handler (callback)

```
var currentTemp = 0;
  $.simpleWeather({
    location: 'New York, New York',
    woeid: '',
    unit: 'f',
    success: function(weather) {
      currentTemp = weather.temp;
      $('#degrees').text(currentTemp); 
    },
    error: function(error) {
      currentTemp = 150;
    }
  });
```